# How do I know sqlIte version and password of a db file?

Tags: sqlite, version, system.data.sqlite, password-recovery

I have a db file but I don't know whether it was created with System.Data.Sqlite or anything else. And I also don't know its password.

Is there any way I can know sqlite password and db file version?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sqlite databases can be encrypted with an extension. If the database is not encrypted, the version number is in clearly indicated in the data file. If the database is encrypted, there is no way to recover the password practically.